# How to view the dashboard in snowflake Streamlit App without snowflake account?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I had created Streamlit App in snowflake. The dashboard can be viewed by the users who are all having access to snowflake account.

is it possible for the users to view the dashboard without even having the snowflake account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Streamlit app and host it on community cloud for free. You can also create a simple authentication with secrets. This way your app can be public and accessible outside Snowflake with access to Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

No, the dashboards cannot be shared outside the account of snowflake as in cross account sharing is not possible.